# How to set baseUrl

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to set the baseurl in my project .
I am using zend framework .But i am new to zend framework and i don't have any idea about how to set it?
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Zend config could help you do this.... please have a look at this page... http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it automatically done by the zend-framework.....

try to echo............

```
echo $this->baseUrl();
```

It will give you the desired answer.......

Comment: If it is in localhost $this->baseurl() it will point to the public folder. For this you many need to set up the base url in your config....

Comment: This is get base url and not set base url

Answer (score 13):

One way is through Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initSetupBaseUrl() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $controller->setBaseUrl('/projects/myapp'); 
}
```

Another way is through application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = /projects/myapp
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html

```
$router     = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller->setControllerDirectory('./application/controllers')
           ->setRouter($router)
           ->setBaseUrl('/projects/myapp'); // set the base url!
$response   = $controller->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this. In your abcd.phtml ( zend framework ).

```
 <?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>
```