# mod_rewrite is appending rule to unrelated links ( side-effect )

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)$ /products.cgi?id=$1 [L]
```

Will rewrite /products.cgi?id=$1 as /products/$1 as expected. But it is also appending /products/ to all links in the page. Suppose i have a link in the products page that is:

```
<a href="/contact-us.cgi">Contact</a>
```

Then the products page will link to:

```
/products/contact-us.cgi
```

That is not something i desire. I want to keep it /contact-us.cgi

Comment: just add a `.` start of your link. `<a href="./contact-us.cgi">Contact</a>` than it will point to `yourdomain.com/contactus.cgi`

Comment: just tried it, did not work

Comment: well, it worked with two dots

Comment: it will be better if you define a `base url` for domain in your config file and append url in the link. you wont need `../` in you links

Comment: You mean rewritebase?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996129/what-exactly-is-a-baseurl it will give you an idea what base url is and how to use it.

Comment: I will have to look at it, the two dots thing only worked for one dir-style rewrite, when it is more than one it does not. I guess i would have to change to ../../ and so on which is not plausible. I'm not using any framework, it is just apache+perl, where am i supposed to set the base url?

Comment: i also don't want to put the full url on href=