# How to redirect to about.jsp?

Tags: html, spring-mvc

So I have this code snippet in spring mvc

```
<a class="nav-item is-hidden-mobile is-active roboto strong letter-space-1" href="">HOME</a>
<a class="nav-item is-hidden-mobile roboto strong letter-space-1" href="about.jsp"> ABOUT </a>
<a class="nav-item is-hidden-mobile roboto strong letter-space-1" href=""> CONTACT </a>
```

But when I click on the `ABOUT`on my landing page, it won't redirect, instead it displays error code 404. Are there other things to fix before I can redirect there, besides in the html file?

Comment: It will give error ,As you did not set the base url in it .

Comment: how do I set it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996129/what-exactly-is-a-baseurl
This should help you get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an endpoint in Controller that will return your about.jsp on some URL like that:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
   @RequestMapping("/hello-about")
   public String getHelloAbout(ModelMap model) {
      return "/WEB-INF/jsp/about.jsp";
   }
}
```

And change your link to point not to the about.jsp file but to the endpoint "/hello-about".

```
<a class="nav-item is-hidden-mobile roboto strong letter-space-1" href="/hello-about"> ABOUT </a>
```

Comment: thank a lot now servlet dispatching make a lot more send now

Comment: So, has the answer helped? I do not understand what you mean

Comment: yes it helped. It makes a lot more sense now, I mean