# zend framework redirection issue : Invalid controller specified

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am developing a project in zend framework 1.12

If I keep all files in root folder everything works fine but If create a new folder and move all files in that nothing works.

Following is my folder structure
application
library
public
index.php
.htaccess

.htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$     public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$     public/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$     public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

application/config/application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"

resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000


[staging : production]

[testing : production]

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root123"
resources.db.params.dbname = "labs"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true
resources.db.params.profiler.class = Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"
```

If I move all folders in labs/  and change in application.ini as
    resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/labs/"

```
http://domainname/  : Works fine     
https://domainname/labs  : gives error
```

How to resolve this. I want to put all files in new folder so that in root i could create some more projects.

ERROR

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (labs)
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/labs/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/html/labs/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/html/labs/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/html/labs/index.php(30): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'labs',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change your "baseUrl" in your config file.

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/labs/"
```

Maybe like that : [How to set baseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802501/how-to-set-baseurl)

Comment: it looks you have to change your config file and your htaccess :

http://blog.digitalpierce.com/2012/08/24/zend-framework-project-in-a-sub-folder/

resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/labs"
And add in your htaccess "RewriteBase /labs"

Answer (score 0):

No need to change anything in .htaccess

application.ini  change as
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/labs"

Add below function in bootsrap.php  and you will be done.

```
protected function _initBaseUrl()
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        $baseUrl = isset($options['settings']['baseUrl']) 
            ? $options['settings']['baseUrl']
            : null;  // null tells front controller to use autodiscovery, the default
        $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
        $front->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
    }
```